# how to create these servlet data into json format i tried this thing

Tags: java, json, servlets

This is my servlet, I successfully read the data from database and displayed it in the browser but I want to display this data in json format can any one tell me

```
package com.file;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class GetDataTable extends HttpServlet{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
res.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:java","java","java");
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from SERIESCHART");

pw.println("DATA "+ "VALUE" + "<br>");
while(rs.next())
{
pw.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2) + "<br>");
}
}
catch (Exception e){
pw.println(e);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You want to export JSON but it looks like you are writing HTML

Comment: no i want these json data into extjs grid. here i connect with db and taking that data only.but how i get these data into json after that how i pass these into extjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

sample code

```
      import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      obj.put("name", "foo");
      obj.put("num",rs.getInt(1));
      obj.put("balance", rs.getString(2));
      obj.put("is_vip", rs.getString(3));

      System.out.print(obj);
```

Comment: here     obj.put("name", "foo");
      obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
      obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
      obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
 you pass static data. but i have taken data dynamically from database. so, i want to pass that db data into json file.

Comment: Personally I'm a fan of [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it has the extra weight of needing a class definition to serialize, but I don't mind the extra typing/classes.

Comment: You can find a lot of tutorials and documentation check this https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
...
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(res.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
writer.beginArray();
while(rs.next())
{
writer.beginObject();
writer.name("DATA").value(rs.getString(1));
writer.name("VALUE").value(rs.getString(2));
writer.endObject();
}
writer.endArray();
writer.close();
....
```

This will fetch your results from db and put the json representation into responce outputstream

Comment: when ever i put this code the output data will want to store some location of the system. but actually these data i want to put in extjs charts

Comment: as you can see that `JsonWriter` is created of response output stream. you can change that to whatever suites you best